# C# - is it possible to check which optional regex group is matched?

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote a simple regex to accept both local file paths (`C:\some\path\to\file`) and network locations (`\\0.0.0.0\some\path\to\file`). I have captured `C:\` and `\\0.0.0.0\` in separate named groups, `<drive>` and `<netloc>` accordingly.

Is it possible in C# to check which group is matched after a "global" match is found? I would like to set flags whether the directory given is local or network. To separate my groups I use the `|` character.

I've found similiar questions, but they do not cover C# and certainly are not easily "transferable".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `Groups` also have a `Success`property.

```
Regex rx=new Regex(@"^((?<drive>[a-z]:\\.*)|(?<netloc>\\\\[^\\]+\\.*))$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.CultureInvariant|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
Match match = rx.Match(somePath);
if (match.Groups["drive"].Success) {
    // drive match
} else if (match.Groups["netloc"].Success) {
    // netloc match
} else {
    // none of these groups matched
}
```

[See MSDN for more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just to clarify - is explicit capture option required for this to work or do you use it only for cleaner regex (no non-matching group markers)?

Comment: @Asunez, Just for cleaner regex, and to reduce the allocations made. It's good practice if you know that you'll only use named groups.